# How to remove AVPlayerViewController from our view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code, how i remove `AVPlayerViewController` from our view.

```
[self.avPlayerViewController.player pause];

self.avPlayerViewController.view.hidden  = YES;
```

I am using above code to hide, but it's not working some times....

```
-(void)playTrailer {
[self.avPlayerViewController.player pause];
NSString *videoFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:self.trailerString ofType:@"mp4" ];
self.avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilePath]];
self.avPlayerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
self.avPlayerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,200,300);
self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer;
[self.view addSubview:self.avPlayerViewController.view];
[self.avPlayerViewController.player play];
}


- (IBAction)playTrailerButton:(UIButton *)sender {
self.trailerString = @"myTrailerName";
[self playTrailer];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the reason in your code are you added the `self.avPlayerViewController.view` to mainview `self.view`.

if you want to remove then use

```
 [self.avPlayerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

**choice 2**

if  you want to unhide the player then use

```
-(void)playTrailer {
[self.avPlayerViewController.player pause];
self.avPlayerViewController.view.hidden = NO;

 }
```

want to hide the player in mainview then use

```
 self.avPlayerViewController.view.hidden = YES;
```

**update answer**

```
-(IBAction)segmentControl:(UISegmentedControl *)sender 
{ 
 [self.avPlayerViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; 
 if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) 
 { 
 [self.avPlayerViewController.player pause]; 
 // [self.avPlayerViewController.view setHidden:YES]; 

 [self playTrailer]; 
 self.animationScrollView.hidden = NO; 
 } 
 else if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) 
 { 
 self.animationScrollView.hidden = YES; 
} 
}
```

Comment: i am using segmented controller with three segments, if we go another segment at that i want to hide or remove this player... how?

Comment: already i am using this code some times it's working, but some times it's not working... [self.avPlayerViewController.player pause];

self.avPlayerViewController.view.hidden = YES;

Comment: - (IBAction)segmentControl:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        [self.avPlayerViewController.player pause];
//        [self.avPlayerViewController.view setHidden:YES];
        [self.avPlayerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];self.animationScrollView.hidden = NO;}if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        self.animationScrollView.hidden = YES;}

Comment: @Lyankar - we dont know what you tried, but we can help based on your need, if given the some additional information it is useful to add or solve ur issue

Comment: @Lyankar - can you attach your project, else explain in which segment you want to hide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134439/discussion-between-lyankar-and-anbu-karthik).